# Cannot create multiple relationship to same master table

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I am very new to SSAS tabular model and I have a very basic problem which I am facing.

I have a master table "city", wherein I have city_code and city_name column. city_code is the primary key.

I have another table sales, wherein I have two columns (pos_city, shipped_to_city) out of many other columns. 
Now, I have to create a many to one relationship from sales tables to city table , from both these columns to master tables..
i.e.

```
pos_city(sales) --> city_code(city) 
shipped_to_city(sales) --> city_code(city)
```

However, when i try to do this for the second relationship, I get an error message saying 'active relationship between sales and city already exists'.

Can anyone suggest how can i get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In tabular you can only have one physical relationship between two tables active at a time.
It depends on how the end user wants to interact with the data but one option is to duplicate your master table. Name one table DimCityOfSale and the other DimCityShippedTo. Then create a physical relationship between the tables
DimCityofSale[citycode] -> Sales[pos_city] 
and 
DimCityShippedTo[citycode] -> Sales[shipped_to_city]